# Menu in appme theme is not synching with hashing id in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using appme theme on wordpress and everything is working good except for the active menu.

https://themes.athenadesignstudio.com/?theme=appme_wp

if you click on the link and click on the menu, you can see that it's not syncing with what it is clicked. For ex: if you click on feature, home will be active, if you click on screen shot, feature will be active and behaves different on different browser as well.

Comment: it's a bug into the theme. You should open a ticket to the support team of this theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main.js file of appme folder, go to this line and as you can see the `scrollTop: h-offset`, so for a work around, i have changed it to `scrollTop: (h-offset)+10`. This will scroll the section a little more and we are set like this untill fix.

```
//Menu
menu:function() {
        //Slick nav
        jQuery(".main-navigation").slicknav({
                prependTo:"#responsive-menu",
                label:"",
                closeOnClick:true
        });

        //Submenu
        jQuery(".nav li").on("mouseenter", function() {
                jQuery(this).children("ul").stop().slideDown(200);
        });

        jQuery(".nav li").on("mouseleave", function() {
                jQuery(this).children("ul").stop().slideUp(200);
        });

        //Header menu
        jQuery(document).on("click", "#navigation ul li a, #responsive-menu ul li a", function() {
                try {
                        var id = jQuery(this).attr("href");
                        var h = parseFloat(jQuery(id).offset().top);
                        var offset = parseInt(jQuery("body").data("offset"), 10);

                        jQuery("body, html").stop().animate({
                                scrollTop:(h-offset)+10
                        }, 800);

                        return false;
                } catch(err) {}
        });

        //Sticky navigation
        if (AppMeOptions.navigation==="sticky") {
                jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
                        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop()>200) {
                                jQuery(".navbar").addClass("sticky-header");
                        } else {
                                jQuery(".navbar").removeClass("sticky-header");
                        }
                });
        }
},
```